# Why does image size and placement change depending on HTML level?

Tags: css, image, resize, alignment, image-resizing

I have a file that displays properly with `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`; images display in the left and right margins, and text is centered. If I change the DTD to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` then the images shift and change size.

I used the markup

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
  <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
  <style>
    .verse {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 2em;
      width: 60%
    }
    
    img.l {
      float: left;
      width: 12%;
      position: fixed;
      left: -20%;
    }
    
    img.r {
      float: right;
      width: 12%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
  <div style="position:absolute; left:20%; width:60%;">
    <H1 style="font-size:4em; text-align:center;">My favorite things</H1>

    <p>
      [Verse]
    </p>
    <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/Silmarillion.png" alt="The Silmarillion">
    <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif" alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
    <p class="verse">
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">Gardening spiders</a>
      <br> And <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">swords that are broken</a>
      <br> Words in the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">Black Speech</a>
      <br> That must not be spoken
      <br>
      <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/11/The_Return_of_the_King_cover.gif" alt="The Return of the King">
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">Unfaithful stewards</a>
      <br> Who don't want their kings
      <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      [hook]
    </p>
    <p class="verse">
      <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f0/Currents_of_space.jpg" alt="The Currents of Space"> When the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc">orc</a> bites, when the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Currents_of_Space">probe</a>      stings
      <br> When I'm feeling bad
      <br> I simply remember my favorite <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragorn">kings</a>
      <br> And I don't feel so bad.
    </p>
    <p>
      [Verse]
      <img class=L src="http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0224.jpg" alt="Astounding Science Fiction vol. XLIII, no. 5, July 1949">
      <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Agent_of_vega.jpg" Alt="<i>Agent of Vega</i> front cover">
    </p>
    <p class="verse">
      Pedllers who drive their
      <br> Mysteriuos wagons
      <br> Pretty young ladies
      <br> Who can speak to dragons
      <br>
      <img class=L src="https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/4/45/ANLGOCT67.jpg" Alt="<i>Analog vol. 80,no 2, October 1967">
      <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/AnneMcCaffrey_Dragonflight.jpg" Alt="<i>Dragonflight</i> front cover">
      <!--
                  http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0445.jpg
                  Analog vol. LXXX, no. 4, December 1967
                  Dragonrider part 1
             -->
      Travelling the Cosmos
      <br> In a
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang">ship who sings</a>
      <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
    </p>
    <br>
    <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/60/ShipWhoSang.jpg" alt="<i>The Ship Who Sang</i> front cover">
    <p>
      [Verse]
    </p>
    <p class="verse">
      <img class=L src="https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/b/b1/FSFMar1959.jpg" alt="The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959">
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies">
Time traveling bar men
</a>
      <br> Who are like no others
      <br> Who are their own fathers
      <br> And are their own mothers
      <br>
      <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Heinlein-face.jpg" alt="Robert Anson Heinlein, Grand Master of SF"> Of all such stories
      <br> Know <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">Heinlein's</a> are kings
      <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      [Verse]
    </p>
    <p class="verse">
      <img class=L src="https://isfdb.org/wiki/images/1/10/LRDDRCRWLR2002.jpg" alt="Lord Darcy"> A <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Darcy_(character)">ducal detective</a> whose
      <br> Aide does the magic
      <br> finds that their cases
      <br> are often quite tragic
      <br> I hope more stories
      <br> still lurk in the wings
      <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
    </p>
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

and expected the same results as with `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the elements from the developer console you can see that the styles aren't getting applied. The problem seems to be related to `img.l` and `img.r` classes, they're defined as lowercase inside the `<style>` tag but uppercase in the html markup, to fix it just update your `<style>` tag with this:

```
.verse {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 60%
}

img.L {
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
  position: fixed;
  left: -20%;
}

img.R {
  float: right;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}
```

Comment: “ the case-sensitivity of document language element names, attribute names, and attribute values depends on the document language” from https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#case-sensitive

Comment: I also had to make the case of class=v consistent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your display is changing because, with the doctype you first used, you are in "quirks mode" where you never want to be as it is like 1999 all over again.

[Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/)

> In the Quirks mode the browsers violate Web format specifications in
> order to avoid “breaking” pages authored according to practices that
> were prevalent in the late 1990s. Previously, different browsers
> implemented different quirks. In particular, in Internet Explorer 6,
> 7, 8 and 9, the Quirks mode is effectively frozen IE 5.5

The current doctype is the second one you used, `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, and has been [required](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#the-doctype) of all HTML documents for at least 15 years.